# Processing images with Watchdog in Python

Tags: python, watchdog, simplecv, python-watchdog

I'm using the watchdog library to detect when new images are created in a specific folder. When watchdog detects a newly created image, I kick off some image processing functions with SimpleCV / OpenCV.

However, the pictures are being taken from a Raspberry Pi camera, and from the below error I don't believe the entire image is saved when it first appears in the directory. (Essentially the file is being saved in "pieces", or multiform).

**Please note** that when I **copy & paste** an image into the respective folder, the script runs successfully.

**Ask:** Is there any way to kick off the image processing only once the entirety of the file has been saved?

```
import time
from SimpleCV import Image
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

class ExampleHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event):
        image = Image(event.src_path)
        do image processing stuff
        print "Got event for file %s" % event.src_path 

observer = Observer()
event_handler = ExampleHandler() # create event handler
observer.schedule(event_handler, path='/path/to/images') # set observer to use created handler in directory
observer.start()

# sleep until keyboard interrupt, then stop + rejoin the observer
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()

observer.join()
```

**Error Dump:**

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/watchdog/observers/api.py", line 241, in run
    self.dispatch_events(self.event_queue, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/watchdog/observers/api.py", line 408, in dispatch_events
    self._dispatch_event(event, watch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/watchdog/observers/api.py", line 403, in _dispatch_event
    handler.dispatch(event)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/watchdog/events.py", line 361, in dispatch
    _method_map[event_type](event)
  File "picture_classifier_cube.py", line 11, in on_created
    image = Image(event.src_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SimpleCV/ImageClass.py", line 1073, in __init__
    self._pil = pil.open(self.filename).convert("RGB")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1980, in open
    raise IOError("cannot identify image file")
IOError: cannot identify image file
```

**Edit** After updating the handler to sleep a few seconds after recognizing a new file, I receive a different error.

```
class ExampleHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event):
        time.sleep(3)
        cans = Image(event.src_path)
```

**Error**

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/path/to/images/test.jpg~'
```

Note that I am capturing an image with the following Pi command: `raspistill -o 'test.jpg'`

Comment: Or, you could just do a try/catch... If you don't care about other errors.

Answer (score 1):

While there may not be a way to know **for certain** if a file is finished being written to without modifying the program that does the writing, you could monitor the file size:

```
from os import stat
from time import sleep

def wait_for_write_finish( filename ):
    last_size, size= -1, 0
    while size!=last_size:
        sleep(1)
        last_size, size= size, stat(filename).st_size
```

You may want to do this with appropriate threading